# In Corda, do nodes check that the messages they receive come from the counterparty node's IP address as listed in the network map?

Tags: corda

In Corda, there is a network map that associates nodes with P2P IP addresses. When a node receives a message, do they check that the IP address they have received the message from is the same as the node's P2P IP address as listed in the network map.

Answer (score 0):

No. The IP addresses on packets sent across the internet regularly change in transit and can be faked.

However, when responding to a counterparty, their P2P address is retrieved from the network map. So although the node can send messages from P2P addresses other than its registered address, it must be able to receive responses on that address.